# Delete records from a table keeping only max value of a group of rows based on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a11afc
I want only those rows in table 1 who are not in table 2 or only the row from table 2 that has maximum value in table 1.
final CourseReg table should look like this.
       'CS-101', 75
       'CS-103', 85
       'CS-104', 78 
After query CourseReg has only those rows that are either not present in EqualCouse Plus the row of EqualCourse that has maximum value in CourseReg. Hopefully it clarify my question

Comment: You want to actually delete rows from `CourseReg` table or just want to select the resultset from it according to your rules?

Answer (score 0):

Ans is below...

```
DELETE FROM dbo.CourseReg 
       WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id) 
              FROM dbo.EqualCourse 
              WHERE dbo.EqualCourse.courseCode = dbo.CourseReg.courseCode) = 0;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a11afc/8/1

Comment: I want the result to have CS-101 75, CS-103 85 and CS-104 78. i.e. both rows that are not in table 2 plus that row of table 2 that has max value in column [totalMarksObtained] of table 1

Answer (score 0):

if you want only those rows in table 1 who are not in table 2

```
 select * from CourseReg where coursecode not in (select coursecode from EqualCourse)
```

Comment: I want the result to have CS-101 75, CS-103 85 and CS-104 78. i.e. both rows that are not in table 2 plus that row of table 2 that has max value in column [totalMarksObtained] of table 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer that you may be looking for.

```
SELECT C.courseCode AS courseCode, C.totalMarksobtained AS marks
FROM [CourseReg] C left join [EqualCourse] E ON C.CourseCode=E.CourseCode
WHERE E.coursecode IS NULL
UNION
SELECT coursecode,  totalmarksobtained AS marks
FROM [CourseReg] RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT Max(totalmarksobtained) maxmarks
FROM [CourseReg] C inner join [EqualCourse] E ON C.CourseCode=E.CourseCode) MXMS ON MXMS.maxmarks = Coursereg.totalmarksobtained
```

Comment: running this on sqlfiddle returns nothing

Comment: @user3171861 That will be because you don't have any data which satisfies the criteria. Add more data to the table you will see something

Comment: I see you comments elsewhere and realise what is the answer you are looking for. I've edited my original answer. if you feel it is the right answer please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** If you need to select a resultset according to your rules you can do

```
WITH non_existent_courses AS
(
  SELECT r.courseCode, r.totalMarksObtained
    FROM CourseReg r LEFT JOIN EqualCourse e
      ON r.courseCode = e.courseCode
   WHERE e.courseCode IS NULL
), max_marks_course AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1 r.courseCode, r.totalMarksObtained
    FROM CourseReg r JOIN EqualCourse e
      ON r.courseCode = e.courseCode
   ORDER BY totalMarksObtained DESC
)
SELECT * 
  FROM non_existent_courses
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM max_marks_course
```

Output:

```
| COURSECODE | TOTALMARKSOBTAINED |
|------------|--------------------|
|     CS-101 |                 75 |
|     CS-103 |                 85 |
|     CS-104 |                 78 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a11afc/23)** demo

Comment: Do you want to actually delete rows from CourseReg table or just want to select the resultset from it according to your rules?

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: I want the result to have CS-101 75, CS-103 85 and CS-104 78. i.e. both rows that are not in table 2 plus that row of table 2 that has max value in column [totalMarksObtained] of table 1

Comment: Ok. Tt's just that your question is ambiguous on that part: *only those rows in table 1 who are not in table 2 **OR ONLY** the row from table 2 that has maximum value in table 1*. It should rather be *and a row...* or as you worded in comment *plus a row...*. But anyway see updated answer and working sqlfiddle example. I hope that helps.